# django data from manytomanyfield intermediate table

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

Currently, I have the following model structure set up in my models.py (stripped down):

```
class Admin(models.Model):
    admin_name = models.CharField(unique = True, blank = False, null = False, max_length = 128, verbose_name = u'admin full name')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.admin_name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
        verbose_name = u'Admin Info'

class Project(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, verbose_name = u'Client')
    description = models.ForeignKey(Description, verbose_name = u'project description')
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(Admin, verbose_name = u'Administrators', through = 'Admin_Payment')

class Admin_Payment(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(Admin, verbose_name = u'Administrator')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, verbose_name = u'project')
    agreed_payment = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 16, decimal_places = 2, blank = True, default = 0)
```

as you can see, I have setup a manytomany relation between my projects and admins using the Admin_Payment as the intermediate table.

My question is how I can make the agreed_payment field (which is in the Admin_Payment class) available to my Project class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django creates an attibute `admin_payment_set` in the Project object that is a "related manager". Access its objects e.g. with "all()". E.g.

```
p = Project.objects.get(pk=1)
paysets = p.admin_payment_set.all()
paysets[0].agreed_payment
```

Comment: BTW: when in this kind of doubts, my best friend is the ipython shell and python's introspection mechanisms. Create an instance of Project, and dir(it), or use ipython's autocompletion to check its attributes